# Parsing XML Data that I receive from UrlFetch

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to parse the data I get from UrlFetch into a spreadsheet, but all I'm getting is undefined can someone show me what i'm doing wrong

The xml is at the address https://dl.dropbox.com/u/11787731/Minecraft/bans.xml

```
function runevery15mins() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("MC Bans");
 sheet.clearContents();
 var banURL = "https://dl.dropbox.com/u/11787731/Minecraft/bans.xml";

 var banXML = UrlFetchApp.fetch(banURL).getContentText();
 var banDOC = Xml.parse(banXML, false);
 var mcuser = banDOC.bans;

 var x = 0;
 for(var c=0; c>mcuser.length;c++){
   var name = mcuser.getElement("username")[c].getText();
   var date = mcuser.getElement("date")[c].getText();
   var reason = mcuser.getElement("reason")[c].getText();
   var duration = mcuser.getElement("duration")[c].getText();



 } 
 sheet.appendRow([name, date, reason, duration]);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some small errors in your code.

For example, the second argument in the for loop needs to be `c<mcuser.length`.

Using the Xml service documentation, this worked for me

```
function runevery15mins() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("MC Bans");
  sheet.clearContents();
  var banURL = "https://dl.dropbox.com/u/11787731/Minecraft/bans.xml";

  var banXML = UrlFetchApp.fetch(banURL).getContentText();
  var banDOC = Xml.parse(banXML, false);
  // Get all the child nodes from the document element that are 'user' nodes
  var mcusers = banDOC.getElement().getElements('user');

  for(var c=0; c<mcusers.length;c++){
    var user = mcusers[c];
    var name = user.getElement('username').getText();
    var date = user.getElement('date').getText();
    var reason = user.getElement('reason').getText();
    var duration = user.getElement('duration').getText();

    sheet.appendRow([name, date, reason, duration]);
 } 
}
```

Note for example that the `sheet.appendRow` line is INSIDE the loop, not outside as you had it before.  I also deleted the X variable, since I didn't see any purpose for it.

I also created a `user` variable, which is an XmlElement, to make it easier to understand how to get the different contents of each node.

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there.

Looks like there was another array you needed to drill down into. Also, your call back to the spreadsheet should be in the loop. Try this:

```
...
var mcuser = banDOC.bans.user;

for(var i in mcuser){
   var name = mcuser[i].getElement("username").getText();
   var date = mcuser[i].getElement("date").getText();
   var reason = mcuser[i].getElement("reason").getText();
   var duration = mcuser[i].getElement("duration").getText();
   sheet.appendRow([name, date, reason, duration])
 }
```